# Wavelength of electron during photoelectric effect

Tags: photons, photoelectric-effect

Consider light of sufficiently enough wavelength not only to remove the electron from metal but also to provide it kinetic energy
.
Now my question is :

If the wavelength of light is Lambda, is the wavelength of electron in motion also lambda

Answer (score 1):

No, the wavelength of the electron escaping from the metal
is not the same as the wavelength of the photon.

Instead, the wavelength $\lambda_e$ of the electron is directly related to its
momentum $p_e$ via the [de Broglie relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave)
$$\lambda_e=\frac{h}{p_e}$$
and the momentum $p_e$ in turn is directly related to its kinetic energy
$E_e$ via
$$E_e=\frac{p_e^2}{2m_e}$$